# Adding a new object to an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, get, addition

I have an object of type 'Bee' which I want to add to my arraylist cells in my class hive but I'm getting a compilation error "Bee cannot be resolved to a variable" on the sidebar in eclipse in my getBee method and I am not really sure if my addBee method is good or not.

My code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Hive {

    ArrayList<Bee> cells = new ArrayList<Bee>();
    int Honey = 10;
    int RoyalJelly = 10;
    int Pollen = 10;    

    public void addBee(Bee b){
        cells.add(b);
    }

    public Bee getBee(int n){
        if(n < cells.size()){
            cells.get(n);
            return Bee;
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }

    public int size(){
        return cells.size();
    }

    public void addHoney(int h){
        Honey = Honey + h;
    }

    public void addRoyalJelly(int r){
        RoyalJelly = RoyalJelly + r;
    }

    public void addPollen(int p){
        Pollen = Pollen + p;
    }

    public int takeHoney(int h2){
        if(h2 <= Honey){
            Honey = Honey - h2;
            return h2;
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public int takeRoyalJelly(int r2){
        if(r2 <= RoyalJelly){
            RoyalJelly = RoyalJelly - r2;
            return r2;
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public int takePollen(int p2){
        if(p2 <= Pollen){
            Pollen = Pollen - p2;
            return p2;
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public void anotherDay(){

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect here:

```
if(n < cells.size()){
    cells.get(n);
    return Bee;
}else{
```

You don't return the class name.  Just return the result of the call to `get`:

```
if(n < cells.size()){
    return cells.get(n);
}else{
```